# Why is the latest cumulative update "not applicable"?

Tags: windows-server-2016

I've just installed Windows 2016 and am attempting to install updates.  For security reasons I am attempting to install the latest cumulative update before attaching the new server to the network.

I've downloaded KB4507459 (the July 2019 cumulative update) from the Microsoft Update Catalog but it won't install; the error message says "The update is not applicable to your computer."

Why is that?  How can I install the latest cumulative update without putting the server on the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to install the latest cumulative updates on a new installation of Windows Server 2016 you must first install the latest servicing stack update.

As of when this answer was posted, that meant installing KB4509091, but to find the most recent available servicing stack update you should always check [security advisory ADV990001](https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-us/security-guidance/advisory/ADV990001).

Once the servicing stack update was installed, KB4507459 no longer detected as not applicable and has now installed successfully.